# How can I write this iferror function in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to clean my data in a column and this is a function i wrote that can be applied to the whole column A.

Can anyone help me how to write a macro for this?

[image]

Comment: Take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how to ask a good question here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Btw, why do you want to write a macro for a working function??

Comment: If would this indeed be written to column A, it would cause a circular error. Please refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can start from here

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        cell.Value = Mid(cell, 2, IIf(InStr(cell, "(") > 0, InStr(cell, "(") - 3, Len(cell)))
    Next
End Sub
```

and adjust it to your needs:

- change "A1" to column A cell you want to start "cleaning" from
- add some additional check  should "(" be found in first two positions of the checked string

Answer (score 0):

If your first value is in A7 and formula is in B7 then write this code -

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A500000").End(xlUp).Row

Range("B7").Value = "=MID(A7,2,IFERROR(FIND(""("",A7)-3,LEN(A7)))"
Range("B7:B" & lastrow).FillDown
```

Hope ths helps!